# What i need to do if aiogram bot doesnt work on server but work on my pc?

Tags: python, server, aiogram

I have a bot written in python using the aiogram library. The problem is that when I run the bot on my computer (windows 10), the bot works fine, as it should. But when I try to run the same bot on the server, the bot does not work. That is, it is clear that the aiogram is turned on (based on the output to the console), and there are no errors, but the bot does not work. At the same time, when I run the bot on the server and then on my computer, I write the corresponding error: `Terminated by other getupdates request`; make sure that only one bot instance is running.

p.s. The token I'm using works for another bot on the server, but not for this bot. That is, one bot works without errors and without problems on the server, the second one does not work. I use the same token, I run each script separately, so errors when running two scripts at the same time using the same token are excluded

How and why is this happening?
(sorry for my english)

idk what i need to write here.

Comment: It is to make sure that only one instance of the bot is running at the same time

Comment: two instances do not start at the same time, I said this